Monitor screens are not being used when connected to integrated HDMI, DVI-d or VGA
After an update my graphics card, EVGA NVIDIA GT 610, was not working right, I only had a blinking cursor on a black screen. I read that the  drivers were no longer being maintained for it and Linux was no longer supporting it.  I pulled the card and connected the monitors directly to the onboard HDMI and DVI-D ports and now I get nothing at all.  The monitor displays no input source found.  I am assuming that the motherboard is still looking for the video card so how do I convince it to use the onboard ports?
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
MB Gigabyte B550M DS3H
Monitors:
(DVI-D port) DELL 2001FP  4:3 1600x1200
(HDMI port) HP Series 5 527sh

I have added a new video card, AMD RX 550 and now I get a black screen with a blinking cursor, so at least I can get to a command line.

I rebooted and pressed the ESC key to get boot options.
Then selected Advanced options for Ubuntu,
then recovery mode.
Ran the dpkg option to fix broken packages. It fixed a few packages.
Ran the clean option to cleanup.
Ran the dpkg option to fix broken packages (again). Nothing to fix.
Selected the resume boot option and got the desktop login screen.
All good.
